# python figure which properties belong to the child class

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have a python class hierarchy as follows:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.c = 3
```

Now when I do something like:

```
obj = B()
obj.__dict__
```

I get:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

is it possible to identify which of these properties belong to the parent class or rather which of these properties are of the child only?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for is well defined in Python. The attributes "belong" to the instance, not to either of the classes. You could have code in `A` that modifies `self.c` or code in `B` that modifies `self.a` or `self.b` (the latter would be normal, the former would be a bit odd, though not illegal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your simple example, you could get the difference in the dict items:

```
print(obj.__dict__.items() - A().__dict__.items())
```

I suppose we should at least to it without knowing the name of the parent class:

```
 print(obj.__dict__.items() - obj.__class__.__bases__[0]().__dict__.items())
```

Comment: That's witty :) ;)

Comment: I would add the caveat you gave in the comment, something along the lines that this isn't well defined in Python since attributes belong to the instance.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that was actually Blckknight's comment so I would not like to take their words. I think the OP might not have worded the question quite correctly and meant more like see what attributes are inherited vs set in the child or else it does not really add up.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham whoops! You're right! I must have seen your handle from the edit.

Comment: That is quite clever!